# How to Filter Spark Dataframe with %in% operator?

Tags: r, sparklyr

I have this dataset that I want to filter:

[image]

it Contains unique values as follows:

```
user_unique <- movie_rating %>% 
  select(userId) %>% distinct() %>% count() %>% collect() %>%
  unlist %>% as.vector
movie_unique <- movie_rating %>% 
  select(movieId) %>% distinct() %>% count() %>% collect() %>%
  unlist %>% as.vector

user_unique_vector <- movie_rating %>% 
  select(userId) %>% distinct() %>% collect() %>%
  unlist %>% as.vector
movie_unique_vector <- movie_rating %>% 
  select(movieId) %>% distinct() %>% collect() %>%
  unlist %>% as.vector
```

[image]

Then I want to filter the whole DF for example for first 50 existing movieID

```
movie_rating %>%
  filter(movieId %in% c(movie_unique_vector[1:50]))
```

But it return unexpected errors:

```
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
no viable alternative at input '(`movieId` IN CASE'(line 3, pos 20)

== SQL ==
    SELECT *
FROM `movie_rating`
WHERE (`movieId` IN CASE WHEN ((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50)) 
THEN ((110, 46850, 147, 46967, 858, 47629, 1221, 48061, 1246, 48516, 1968, 48738, 2762, 48783, 2918, 49530, 2959, 50068, 4226, 50872, 4878, 51540, 5577, 53972, 33794, 54272, 54503,
```

How may I filter this?

Edit: If anyone interested with the DF sources, here it is: `https://gofile.io/d/6RQvc1`

Comment: Would you please explain a bit more based on what criteria you would like to filter?

Comment: @Anoushiaravan R So, in this Movie Rating dataset, I would like to filter for some subset of unique movieId that I can choose which movie, so that I would get a smaller dataframe that contains an example of existing users that watch movie rating in smaller scale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't seem to find an answer directly filtering spark dataframe using `%in%` operator based by vector matchings.. so I had to make a custom function by filtering directly from SQL, which is look like this:

```
spark_filter_vector <- function(spark_df_name="", column_name_to_match="", 
                                vector_to_match=c(), log=FALSE, inverse=FALSE){
  string_sql <- ""
  if(inverse){
    string_sql <- paste0("SELECT * FROM ", spark_df_name, " WHERE ",column_name_to_match, " NOT IN(")
  }else{
    string_sql <- paste0("SELECT * FROM ", spark_df_name, " WHERE ",column_name_to_match, " IN(")
  }
  for(a in 1:length(vector_to_match)){
    if(log){
      print(paste0("a = ",a))
    }
    if(a < length(vector_to_match)){
      string_sql <- paste0(string_sql, vector_to_match[a],",")
    }
    else if(a == length(vector_to_match)){
      string_sql <- paste0(string_sql, vector_to_match[a],")")
    }
  }
  sdf_sql(spark_conn, string_sql)
}
```

So that I can implement vector matching like this:

```
movie_filtered <- spark_filter_vector("movie_rating", "movieId", movie_unique_vector[1:50])
movie_filtered <- spark_filter_vector("movie_rating", "movieId", movie_unique_vector[c(2,7,8,12)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider working with 'join' rather than `%in%` (although latter might be be natural for a R user).

1. Create a spark dataframe with top 50 unique movies
2. Then, `inner_join` with the original spark dataframe (`movie_rating`).

```r
movie_unique_sdf = movie_rating %>% 
  select(movieId) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  slice(1:50)

movie_rating %>%
  inner_join(movie_unique_sdf, by = "movieId")
```